# Setting variable, but it's returning null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Alright, so I've been attempting to solve this for hours, but I just cannot find the reason this is happening. So I have three classes involved, in one:

```
public void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    config = new File(m.getUser() + "AppData/Roaming/pseudpixel/config.cfg");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(m.getUser() + "AppData/Roaming/pseudopixel/config.cfg");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(temp.startsWith("screenName")) {
            tempCache = temp.split(":");
            v.setScreenName(tempCache[1]);
        } else if(temp.startsWith("screenWidth")) {
            tempCache = temp.split(":");
            v.setScreenWidth(Integer.parseInt(tempCache[1]));
        } else if(temp.startsWith("screenHeight")) {
            tempCache = temp.split(":");
            v.setScreenHeight(Integer.parseInt(tempCache[1]));
        } else if(temp.startsWith("debug")) {
            tempCache = temp.split(":");
            v.setDebug(tempCache[1]);
        }

        br.close();
    }
}
```

I set the values in the value class:

```
public void setScreenName(String s) {
    screenName = s;
    m.log("ScreenName Set:   " + getScreenName() + "\n");
}

public String getScreenName() {
    return screenName;
}

public void setScreenWidth(int i) {
    screenWidth = i;
    m.log("ScreenWidth Set:  " + getScreenWidth() + "\n");
}

public Integer getScreenWidth() {
    return screenWidth;
}

public void setScreenHeight(int i) {
    screenHeight = i;
    m.log("ScreenHeight Set: " + getScreenHeight() + "\n");
}

public Integer getScreenHeight() {
    return screenHeight;
}

public void setDebug(String b) {
    if(b.equals("true")) {
        debug = true;
        m.log("Debug Set:        " + getDebug() + "\n");
    } else {
        debug = false;
        m.log("Debug Set:        " + getDebug() + "\n");
    }
}

public boolean getDebug() {
    return debug;
}
```

and that all works fine, according to my logging. But when I try to get a value with a get method from this class, it returns a nullpointer exception. Basically all of the values are returned null when I call the get method from an outside class. They seem to do this immediately after the `loadFile()` method finishes.

Really sorry about how stupid this all sounded. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote this. I fixed it all with a single line of code.

Comment: Have you heard of debugging?  I hear it can help solve these kinds of problems.  Plus, adding code from the call site (where it fails) would probably be more useful.

Comment: Without context there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: I have to agree with the folks above -- there's no way short of via ESP to guess what you're doing wrong based on the information that you've presented. Possibly your variable shadowing, but who knows?

Comment: "when I try to set a value with a get method"...well there's your problem right there! A `set` works better for setting.  Seriously, though, if you could post a short little program that demonstrates the issue people would be able to help you.  Even the stack trace would be a start.  If you're running in an IDE then set a breakpoint and run the program in debug mode. You'll be able to step through the program line-by-line and examine values at every point.

Comment: You should relay what the fix *was*, otherwise this entire exercise was useless, and a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `set` a value with a `get` method, that's paradoxical. Unless, of course, you hate the people reading your code and use `get` for setting and `set` for getting variables.

I'm thinking that you are trying to set some other value using this class's `get` methods, in which case you should post them, and make an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). But since you didn't post that code I can't be much help here.

However, it doesn't look like you have a `constructor` to initialize all of the values:

```
public Value() {
  screenName = "";
  screenWidth = 0;
  screenHeight = 0;
  debug = false;
}
```

The point of a `constructor` is to make all of your values not `null`. Since you don't have one, everything is still `null`.

Then, when you initialize `v` (assuming it's type is `Value`), you call the constructor like this:

```
Value v = new Value();
```

The constructor can also take arguments to pre-set the values to something chosen by the instantiation.

Comment: Technically, you could, if the method was poorly-named.

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes, but I like pretending that everyone is better than that.

Comment: You're young; you'll grow out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that your `br.close()` is within the while loop. Any chance that has something to do with it?

Comment: +1 I think you nailed it.  He'll only read at most one line from his config.cfg file and then stop processing.